# Change label in the middle of a list

Tags: numbering, enumerate, enumitem

I tried to use `moreenum` and `enumitem` to create a list numbered in hex. For flavour, I want the label to be `0x##` (or `0x0#` up to `0x0F`) if possible. This was my first approach:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=0x0\enumhex*]
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
        \setcounter{enumi}{14}
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Sadly the `0` is now printed in front of every value. This compiles to the first column, but I'd like to achieve the way printed in the second. In other words: check the counter and ignore the `0` if necessary.

```
0x01     0x01
0x02     0x02
0x0D     0x0D
0x0F     0x0F
0x010    0x10
```

Is it possible to define a command so `[label=0x\somecommand]` will print the desired result?

I tried using `\newif` and toggles in the body of the list, but it didn't work. I'd also prefer to be able to define a function using conditionals based on the counter value for this, since it might be more useful in future projects.

```
\newif\ifNotLargerF
....
\begin{enumerate}[label=0x\ifNotLargerF{0}\fi\enumhex*]
    \NotLargerFtrue
    \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
    \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
    \NotLargerFfalse
    \setcounter{enumi}{14}
    \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
    \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
    \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a protected number test into the label.  Here, `\padz` adds a zero if the `enumi` count is 15 or less.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{moreenum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\def\padz{\ifnum\value{enumi}>15\relax\else0\fi}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\ttfamily0x\protect\padz\enumhex*}]
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
        \setcounter{enumi}{14}
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
        \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is marked as accepted because aside from achieving the desired result it also uses a test to determine whether to print the `0` or not. In my opinion, it's therefore more universal than the other answer, since it could be adapted to change the label in other ways, i.e. different symbols or different commands, depending on the value of `enumi`.
Thanks for showing me how to use number tests properly.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`moreenum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moreenum) uses [`fmtcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) as its "number translation workhorse", you can use `\padzeroes[2]` to prepend a sufficient number of zeroes to your enumeration:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{moreenum,enumitem}

\padzeroes[2]
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\texttt{0x\enumHex*}]
  \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
  \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
  \setcounter{enumi}{14}
  \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
  \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
  \item Thou shalt not follow the null pointer.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would mark both answers as accepted if I could. This way seems to be simpler and less error prone than the other solution, but affects every list in my document. 
I guess there's a workaround so it only affects lists in a specific environment, I'm pretty much a beginner though so I don't know how to do that properly.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer and setting the tags correctly.